# How to link tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables and i want to create a third that references the other two.

`stock_group` has `groupno` as primary key
`stock_group2s` also has `groupno` as primary key

I want to create table called `stock_group3s`, with 5 columns:

```
key int AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  
groupno  INT
group1  [stock_group.groupno]
group2  [stock_group2s.groupno]
name   VARCHAR (30)
```

The two linked columns then must contain only a value that can be found in their referenced tables.

How do  set this up? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Comment: create a foreign key constraint.

Comment: OK, I tried that (after reading a few posts ) but I must have had the wrong syntax because it won't create the table.

Comment: post the sql that you tried that has the problem

Comment: OK, couldn't find it again. @Nasir answer has worked for me. Thankyou Radar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you are looking for

```
 create table stock_group (groupno int primary key)

create table stock_group2s(groupno int primary key)

create table stock_group3s
(
    IDkey int PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,groupno  INT
    ,group1  INT 
    ,group2 INT
    ,name   VARCHAR (30)
) 

ALTER TABLE stock_group3s  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_stock_group3s_stock_group FOREIGN KEY(group1)
REFERENCES stock_group (groupno)


ALTER TABLE stock_group3s  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_stock_group3s_stock_group2s FOREIGN KEY(group2)
REFERENCES stock_group2s (groupno)
```

Comment: you can create 3rd one only and then foreign key. If you want to create script to reuse; you can use if exists statement.